# AutocompleteInput: change format of query

Tags: admin-on-rest

Is it possible to, for example, change the "q" query key in the AutocompleteInput?

The default `{ "q": "foobar" }` doesn't work with my API where `"q"` would be correspondent to a model key, e.g `productName` to make the filtering.

**EDIT: (CLOSED)**
Realizing this isn't really AoR's responsibility I've opted to instead modify my restClient to handle a `"q"` keyed request.

**EDIT 2:**
This can also be done in the view layer by using the `filterToQuery` prop on ReferenceInput/ReferenceArrayInput to modify the query sent to your restClient

Comment: You can check JqueryUi's autocomplete here. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: I'm using the react package admin-on-rest, as tagged, which utilizes material-ui.

Comment: What's your use case exactly ?

Comment: Say I want to search for a specific key, such as `productName` without needing to handle the conversion from `q` to `productName` in the backend.

Comment: Please update your question with a full description of your usecase and, if you can, an extract of your current code

Comment: Updated the question with a more descriptive usecase and a closing statement. Thanks.

Comment: @Gildas I must say. A huge huge amount of SO questions on AOR can be handled by the answer I have given below. I think we should look at more broad based documentation so people realize what it is that the rest client does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this at the client level as well. Just use a custom Rest Client or use a RestClient wrapper to intercept the call to your API and format the request URL depending on the value of the q filter.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, I realized this was the way to go just moments after posting the question... Sorry!
Hopefully this thread can help others find the way I did though.

Comment: Actually, when working on other things I realized the `filterToQuery` prop on ReferenceArrayInput was what I was looking for originally.

Comment: Hmm AOR is moving fast. The above was the only sensible solution I found for things just 3 months ago.